# Is scaling out a NoSql database in the cloud easier than scaling out an RDBMS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, scalability, rdbms, nosql

The company I work at uses Sql Server mainly for persistence and are planning to move to AWS. I hear that scaling out RDBMS in cloud is really hard and costly because of the Geographical regions that you have to cover for fail-over scenarios. does moving to a NoSql database alleviate the problem of scaling out in the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what technology you use. You challenges on scaling would be very similar.

> I hear that scaling out RDBMS in cloud is really hard and costly because of the Geographical regions

I don't agree. That's probably where cloud providers has most benefits. Say for example with one click you can enable multy-az RDS. Yes it's not cross -region but fault-tolerant for sure. Alternatively you can dump DB to S3 and enable recently launched cross-region replication of the data.
Another example is AWS Redshift that enables you to resize warehouse with no downtime.